# React Insert/Remove Row In Array Problem Not Updating

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

Need advise. I have a basic parent (AddressList) and child (Address) component hierarchy. The add remove buttons are in the Address component.

My issue is, while the user selects the dropdown and textfield, the values do get updated, but how do I update the array in the Parent component? When I press the + button to add a new row, the array does not update show the row with the filled fields. All rows are back to their initial state.

I tried to use useReducer() but I get the same result.

Thoughts?

```
const AddressList = (props) => {
  const [addresses, setAddresses] = React.useState(props.addresses);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    let rows = [...addresses];
    rows.push(AddressModel);
    setAddresses(rows);
  };

  const handleRemoveRow = (index) => {
    let rows = [...addresses];
    rows.splice(index, 1);
    setAddresses(rows);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { addresses.map((address, index) =>
        <Address
          index={index}
          item={address}
          key={Math.random()}
          handleAddRow={handleAddRow}
          handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow}/>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AddressList;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  root: {
    display: 'inline-flex',
    maxWidth: 800,
    minWidth: 300,
    padding: 10,
    width: '100%'
  }
}));

const types = ['Home', 'Work'];

const Address = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // const [address, setAddress] = React.useState(props.item);
  const [address, setAddress] = useReducer((myArray, { type, value }) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "add":
        return [...myArray, value];
      case "remove":
        return myArray.filter((_, index) => index !== value);
      default:
        return myArray;
    }
  }, [address]);

  const handleAddressChange = name => event => {
    setAddress({ ...address, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const index = props.index;
  const handleAddRow = props.handleAddRow;
  const handleRemoveRow = props.handleRemoveRow;

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root} spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
        <TextField
          id="type"
          label="Email Type"
          margin="normal"
          value={address.type}
          onChange={handleAddressChange('type')}
          fullWidth
          select>
          {types.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={9}>
        <TextField
          id="address"
          label="Address"
          margin="normal"
          value={address.address}
          onChange={handleAddressChange('address')}
          fullWidth
          required/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={1}>
        {
          index === 0 ?
            <IconButton className={classes.button} aria-label="add" onClick={() => handleAddRow()}>
              <AddIcon/>
            </IconButton>
          :
            <IconButton className={classes.button} aria-label="delete" onClick={() => handleRemoveRow(index)}>
              <DeleteIcon/>
            </IconButton>
        }
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Address;

export const AddressModel = {
    id: 0,
    type: 'Home',
    address: ''
};
```

Comment: can you build a basic reproduction of your project and problem using codesandbox?

Comment: hi will. ok ill see what i can do, i have not tried codesandbox. will check it out

Answer (score 1):

I've created a working mock-up in codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-wind-82pxr)

The main changes are to first update your Address model so each item has an `id` rather than relying on the index.

```
const addresses = [
  { id: 0, address: "home address 1", type: "Home" },
  { id: 1, address: "home address 2", type: "Home" },
  { id: 2, address: "work address 1", type: "Work" }
];
```

... then to move your updating code for your address and type to the parent. So you only have your state in one place and you deal with all the updates there.

So your `AddressList` now looks like this:

```
const AddressList = props => {
  const [addresses, setAddresses] = React.useState(props.addresses);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setAddresses([
      ...addresses,
      { id: addresses.length, address: "new address", type: "Home" }
    ]);
  };

  const handleRemoveRow = id => {
    const rows = addresses.filter(address => address.id !== id);
    setAddresses(rows);
  };
  const updateAddress = (id, ev) => {
    const rows = addresses.map(item =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, address: ev.target.value } : item
    );
    setAddresses(rows);
  };
  const updateType = (id, ev) => {
    const rows = addresses.map(item =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, type: ev.target.value } : item
    );
    setAddresses(rows);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {addresses.map((address, index) => (
        <Address
          index={index}
          item={address}
          key={address.id}
          handleAddRow={handleAddRow}
          handleRemoveRow={handleRemoveRow}
          updateType={updateType}
          updateAddress={updateAddress}
        />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And your address:

```
const Address = props => {
  const {
    updateType,
    updateAddress,
    item,
    index,
    handleAddRow,
    handleRemoveRow
  } = props;
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
        <TextField
          id="type"
          label="Email Type"
          margin="normal"
          value={item.type}
          onChange={ev => updateType(item.id, ev)}
          fullWidth
          select
        >
          {types.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
              {option}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={9}>
        <TextField
          id="address"
          label="Address"
          margin="normal"
          value={item.address}
          onChange={ev => updateAddress(item.id, ev)}
          fullWidth
          required
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={1}>
        {index === 0 ? (
          <IconButton aria-label="add" onClick={handleAddRow}>
            Add
          </IconButton>
        ) : (
          <IconButton
            aria-label="delete"
            onClick={() => handleRemoveRow(item.id)}
          >
            Remove
          </IconButton>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out will. This works. I overcomplicated things.